# Removal of leaves in a binary tree

Tags: java, tree

I'm confused on why my removal method of leaves in a BST is not working. If I assign 0 to the data, its reflected in the tree, but when I assign null to the node, it's still able to be referenced in the BST traversal.

```
public void removeLeaves(){
    removeLeaves(getRoot());
}

private void removeLeaves(IntTreeNode node) {
    if (node == null)
        return;
    else if( node.left == null && node.right == null){
        node.data = 0;  //im finding the leave nodes correctly
        node = null;    //but its not removing them
    }
    else {
        removeLeaves(node.left);
        removeLeaves(node.right);
    }
}

        overallRoot
        ____[7]____
       /           \
    [3]             [9]
   /   \           /   \
[0]     [0]     [0]     [8]
                           \
                            [0]
```

Could somebody explain why this is not working as intended?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example tree , consider `9`

```
 9.left => null
 9.right => address of 8
```

when you assign `node.data = 0;` , node has address of `8` so `0` will be reflected in the tree.

But when you do `node =null`, you are just changing the variable `node`. you are not doing any operation on `address of 8`.

I think what you are hoping to happen is  by doing `node = null` is:

```
      address of 8 = null
```

which is actually not possible, because you are just changing the variable `node`.

Say address of `8` is `0XABCD`, so `node = 0XABCD`.
when you do `node.data=0` as `node` has address `0XABCD`, `0XABCD.data` will be changed to `0`. but when you do `node = null`, you are just assigning a new value to a variable `node`, you are not doing any operation on the original address `0XABCD`.

What you actually have to do is

```
  if(node.left!= null && node.left.left == null && node.left.right ==null)
     node.left =null

  if(node.right!= null && node.right.left == null && node.right.right ==null)
     node.right =null
```

**UPDATE**

What you are trying to do is something like this:

```
  Foo foo = new Foo();
  Foo anotherFoo = foo;

  anotherFoo.value = something; // both foo.value and anotherFoo.value will be changed to "something", because of the reference.

  anotherFoo = null; 
  // here you are expecting foo also to be null which is not correct.
```

Comment: Yes, I was trying to assign null to the address but I suppose it just does not work that way in Java.  Appreciate the explanation.  Putting working code in a new post.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void removeLeaves () {
    if (getRoot() != null) 
        removeLeaves (getRoot());
}

private IntTreeNode removeLeaves (IntTreeNode node) {
    if (getRoot().left == null && getRoot().right == null) {
        setRoot(null);
    } else {
        if (node.left != null) {
            if (node.left.left == null && node.left.right == null) 
                node.left = null;             
            else 
                removeLeaves(node.left);
        }
        if (node.right != null) {
            if (node.right.right == null && node.right.left == null) 
                node.right = null;      
            else 
                removeLeaves(node.right);     
        }
    }
    return node;
}
```